# submit form with jquery by click on table cell

Tags: jquery, form-submit

How is this possible that the form submit only the "input" field of the clickt table cell

```
<form id="switch" method="POST">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>some content<input type="hidden" name="switch_value" value="1"></td>
            <td>some content<input type="hidden" name="switch_value" value="2"></td>
            <td>some content<input type="hidden" name="switch_value" value="3"></td>
            <td>some content<input type="hidden" name="switch_value" value="4"></td>
            <td>some content<input type="hidden" name="switch_value" value="5"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

Comment: You disable the rest of the inputs that were not clicked and then submit the form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<form id="switch" method="POST">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td><label>some content<input type="radio" name="switch_value" value="1"></label></td>
            <td><label>some content<input type="radio" name="switch_value" value="2"></label></td>
            <td><label>some content<input type="radio" name="switch_value" value="3"></label></td>
            <td><label>some content<input type="radio" name="switch_value" value="4"></label></td>
            <td><label>some content<input type="radio" name="switch_value" value="5"></label></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#switch input[type="radio"]').change(function(){
    $('#switch').submit();
  });
});
</script>
```

I wrapped the text and the radio buttons between `label` that way, even if you use css to hide the `radio buttons`, the text would propagate the event down to the radio button.

Comment: This works but, i've the problem that the radio buttons needs additional Space in the Table, even if i hide the button with css

Comment: IF you use css to hide them, `display:none; width:0`, then they really should not occupy any space.