# How to $_POST without clicking button?

Tags: php, jquery, html, forms

Before, i have a form that has a radio button and of course, it submits the value in the radio button when pressing submit.

but how do i do it if i dont want radio buttons anymore? When pressing the table cell or row will automatically submit the value to the next page without the submit button?

```
<form method="post" action="billing.php">
    <table width="900" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0" id='center'>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="radio" name="carrier" <?php if (isset($carrier) && $carrier=="LBC") echo "checked";?>  value="LBC"></td>
            <td><img src="../paymentoptions/LBC.jpg" alt="LBC" class="picture"/></td>
            <td><p>The Shipping takes 1-2 days for NCR and 2-3 days for any provincial. Payment method only available is through BPI Bank Deposit<p>
                <div id='price'> Additional ₱250 </div></td>

        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="radio" name="carrier" <?php if (isset($carrier) && $carrier=="PickUp") echo "checked";?>  value="PickUp"></td>
            <td><img src="../paymentoptions/Pick-up.jpg" alt="Pick-Up" class="picture"/></td>
            <td><p>Personally pick up your merchandise at our office. Free of Charge. Office hours: 10:00 am to 5:00 pm<p>
                <div id='price'> Free!! </div></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

how do i make it submit without using submit button or the radio button, for when i press the row, it submits the value to the next page and i go to the next page.

thank you

EDIT.

```
<table width="900" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0" id='centerdown'>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="radio"  name="payment" <?php if (isset($payment) && $payment=="BPI") echo "checked";?>  value="BPI"></td>
        <td><img src="../paymentoptions/BPI.jpg"></td>
        <td><p>Pay by BPI bank deposit (we need confirmation of payment through email.)<p></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td><input type="radio"  name="payment" <?php if (isset($payment) && $payment=="PickUp") echo "checked";?>  value="PickUp"></td>
        <td><img src="../paymentoptions/Pick-up.jpg"></td>
        <td><p>Pick up. You have 5 days reservation period. You pay for the merchandise upon pick-up<p></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: then use javascript (jquery tagged) to trigger submit on row click

Comment: Does [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26014630/submit-form-with-jquery-by-click-on-table-cell) help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use the rows to submit it. Consider this markup:

```
<form method="post" action="billing.php">
    <table width="900" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0" id='center'>
        <tr class="row_submit">
               <!-- ^^ simple class assignment -->
            <td><input type="radio" name="carrier" <?php if (isset($carrier) && $carrier=="LBC") echo "checked";?>  value="LBC"></td>
            <td><img src="../paymentoptions/LBC.jpg" alt="LBC" class="picture"/></td>
            <td><p>The Shipping takes 1-2 days for NCR and 2-3 days for any provincial. Payment method only available is through BPI Bank Deposit<p>
                <div id='price'> Additional ₱250 </div></td>

        </tr>
        <tr class="row_submit">
            <td><input type="radio" name="carrier" <?php if (isset($carrier) && $carrier=="PickUp") echo "checked";?>  value="PickUp"></td>
            <td><img src="../paymentoptions/Pick-up.jpg" alt="Pick-Up" class="picture"/></td>
            <td><p>Personally pick up your merchandise at our office. Free of Charge. Office hours: 10:00 am to 5:00 pm<p>
                <div id='price'> Free!! </div></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

Then on your JS:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('tr.row_submit').on('click', function(e){
        $('form').submit();
    });
});
</script>
```

Then on PHP:

```
$info_table = array(
    'LBC' => array(
        'price' => 250,
        'payment' => 'BPI',
    ),
    'PickUp' => array(
        'price' => 0,
        'payment' => '',
    ),
);

if(isset($_POST['carrier'])){
    echo $_POST['carrier'];
    $price = $info_table[$_POST['carrier']]['price'];
    $payment = $info_table[$_POST['carrier']]['payment'];
    echo '<br/>' . $price . '<br/>';
    echo $payment;
}
```

Comment: Just to clarify since it seems the OP is newish to PHP/Web.  You should read up on sanitizing your inputs and not directly use the $_POST variable but otherwise this is the right way to do it

Comment: @DaOgre we'll if you want to prepare statements, then sure of course, anyway thats a whole another topic, it'll get too long, but of course i understand your concern

Comment: Oh it worked. hehe. Thank you. Hmm. How do i place 2 values when using this one? because I also need $payment and $carrier to be submitted, it is not included in the code. That is why i dont like to use radio button because only 1 can be submitted, or am i wrong? thank you.

Comment: @VinceAgno you really don't need to use another input element inside the form, just use a predefined array that corresponds to the radio button

Comment: @VinceAgno eto bro check my revision on the PHP part

Comment: @Ghost i've added the new table, i need the payment option to also send values to the next page. Or automatic, when pressing LBC, the value "BPI" will also be sent.

Comment: @VinceAgno same logic, just put a predefined set of info, i revised it into a multi dimensional, so that if you want to put other stuff in it, just add it

Comment: @Ghost I will remove the payment options, and only shipping options will remain, that's why i need more than one value for a radio button, so i dont have to click the payment option. for example i pressed LBC, automatically  $payment is BPI like that.

Comment: @VinceAgno have you tried my answer? thats why i used a pre defined values on an array, so that you'll only need 1 input which is the radio button, after the php gets the radio button value, there is a pre defined values that are already set on the array, check my answer

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function submit(){
        var data = $("form[action=billing.php]").serialize();
        $.ajax({
            url: "billing.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: data,
            success: function(out){
                $(body).html(out);
            }
        });
    }
$(document).ready(function(){
$('tr.row_submit').click(function(){submit();});
}

</script>
```

I wish it works!

Comment: Please expand on your answer to explain what your code does.  Teach OP to fish :)

Comment: @dimo414 It selects the billing form element and serialize its inputs in this way carrier=value then submit this form via xhr after clicking on tr with the class 'row_submit' finally the document body will be refreshed with the form response